# change Jtable Cell Value

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a jtable that keep book file records and sho them.

I create a "Borrow" jbutton that when clicked to a row that not borrowed, The "Borrow Status" of that row should change to "Yes".

I use this codes, but did not changed!

```
public class user_AllBooks extends AbstractTableModel{
BookInformation book_info=new BookInformation();
String[] columns=new String[]{"Book Name","Book Date", "Book ID","Borrow Status"};
ArrayList<BookInformation> bData=new ArrayList<BookInformation>();

public user_AllBooks(){
    try{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("AllBookRecords.txt"));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            bData.add(initializeBookData(line));
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){

    }
}

public BookInformation initializeBookData(String myline){
    BookInformation book_infos=new BookInformation();
    String[] celledLine=myline.split("     ");
    book_infos.setBookName(celledLine[0]);
    book_infos.setBookDate(celledLine[1]);
    book_infos.setBookID(celledLine[2]);
    book_infos.setBorrowStatus(celledLine[3]);
    return book_infos;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int col){
    return columns[col];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    if(bData != null){
        return bData.size();
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columns.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    BookInformation bookInf=bData.get(rowIndex);
    Object value;

    switch(columnIndex){     
        case 0:
            value=bookInf.getBookName();
            break;
        case 1:
            value=bookInf.getBookDate();
            break;
        case 2:
            value=bookInf.getBookID();
            break;
        case 3:
            value=bookInf.getBorrowStatus();
            break;
        default :
            value="...";
    }
    return value;    
}
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class user_AllBooksM extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
user_AllBooks uAllBooks=new user_AllBooks();
final JTable bTable=new JTable(uAllBooks);
JButton borrowButton;
public user_AllBooksM(){
    setTitle("All Books");
    exitButton=new JButton("Exit");
    borrowButton=new JButton("Borrow");
    borrowButton.addActionListener(this);
    JPanel Bpanel=new JPanel();
    Bpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(bTable);
    Bpanel.add(sp);
    Bpanel.add(borrowButton);
    this.add(Bpanel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(300, 60, 550, 550);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        borrowInitialize(bTable.getSelectedRow());  
}

public void  borrowInitialize(int row){
    if(uAllBooks.getValueAt(row, 3).equals("yes")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This Book Was Borrowed");
    }
    else{
        uAllBooks.setValueAt("Yes", row, 3);
        uAllBooks.fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new user_AllBooksM();
}

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have not overridden `setValueAt` in `user_AllBooks` . You should

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To override `setValueAt` You should use:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
{
    BookInformation book_infos = bData.get(row);
    if (col==0)
    book_infos.setBookName((String)value);
    else if (col==1)
    book_infos.setBookDate((String)value);
    else if (col==2)
    book_infos.setBookID((String)value);
    else if (col==3)
    book_infos.setBorrowStatus((String)value);
    fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);
}
```

Define this method within class `user_AllBooks`

Comment: There should be no need to call fireTableDataChanged within setValueAt, because a normal editable table will do this for you. Might be better to have a setBorrowed method instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer : I add this method for the assurance that the changed value would surely be reflected in table. Is is unnecessary call?

Comment: Is this method specialy for setBorrow Or not?

Comment: Is this method specialy for setBorrow Or not?

Comment: @Sajjad-HiFriend: This method is generalized and can be used for changing value in any cell of JTable.

Comment: No, under the conditions that the OP wants to use it, it is required, but under normal table operations it isn't.  The `JTable` would update the view automatically after calling the method.  This means you will now get to update request, slowing down the application as the table could be painted twice.  `fireTableDataChanged` is probably not the best choice here, as it will required the `JTable` to completely repaint itself.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: yes I thought about this point . And consequently removed that line from the method..

Comment: I would mention to the OP that if they call setValueAt directly, they will need to update the view of the table themselves, otherwise the table will no know of the change

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I think OP is doing that in his code after setting the value of cell..

Comment: So long as the next question isn't "why isn't my table changing when I change the value?" ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: hahahaha..yeah you are right :) . By the way I have seen your answers in many Questions . They are very innovative and exact. It is always a pleasure to read your answers.:)

Comment: +1, for implementing setValueAt(). As already suggested, you should NOT invoke fireTableDataChanged(). However, you SHOULD invoke fireTableCellUpdated().

Comment: @VishalK When i do this, it changed in jtable, but when run program again' it was not changed, because not changed in text file

Comment: @Sajjad-HiFriend What is the format of your file? is it in csv form or any other??

Comment: You could use FileWriter to write the contents of JTable in the same File. Files contents couldnot be changed dynamically while you are reading  it. My suggestion is that , when you done with changing the cell values of JTable , fire an actionListener and write all the contents of JTable on that file using FileWriter or BufferedWriter ..

Answer (score 2):

You have overridden the getValueAt method. So it always returns value from your `bData` arraylist.

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    BookInformation bookInf=bData.get(rowIndex);
```

So you need to implement the setValueAt method also in your table model so change actual data in the `bData` arraylist.

Also note that `bTable.getSelectedRow()`  will give you selected row in terms of the view. In model the index might be different if the table is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `TableModel#setValueAt`, but you would also become responsible for updating the table, which breaks the MCV model.

Instead, you could add a `setBorrowed` method to your `user_AllBooks` class.

```
public void setBorrowed(int row, boolean borrowed) {
    BookInformation book = bData.get(row);
    book.setBorrowedState(borrowed);
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, 3);
}
```

Comment: -1, This IS the job of the setValueAt() method. First it updates the data structure containing the data of the model. Then the TableModel is responsible for notifying the table when the contents of a cell are changed. The TableModel does this by invoking the fireTableCellUpdated(...) method the same as you have done here. This could be considered a convenience method that invokes  setValueAt(borrowed, row, 3).

Comment: @camickr Thank you for at least telling me why I'm a douche bag ;) - It is appreciated.  I had a look at `DefaultTableModel` and it does, indeed, use `fireTableCellUpdated`.  My concern is (and I hope you can help me here), I've never had to call it when using a `AbstractTableModel` as the table seems to automatically update itself.  Is it overkill to fire another event, potentially cause a double repaint?? (Sure in most cases it's a single cell, just curious on another view point)

Comment: Data from the editor is saved to the model using the setValueAt(...) method. Then the editor is removed from the table which results in the cell being repainted. So you are correct that the table will be repainted with the new value even if the setValueAt(...) method doesn't fire the update event. However, it is definitely the responsibilty of the Model to notify the View when data changes. The double repaint is caused by the way the JTable implements the editing code.

Comment: @camickr I agree it's the responsibility of the model to fire the event (the fact that the abstract implementation uses `protected` methods is a good suggestion). Good or bad, that's what the answer states, the (good or bad) assumption I've made is `setValue` doesn't fire the event, in that case, we need a method in the model that can.  The bad here is needing to cast the model, which is a valid concern, the good is knowing the model is providing notification back to the client (via `fireTabelCellUpdated`). If that makes sense :P (ps I don't think you're wrong - just seeking clarification)

Comment: setValueAt(...) should fire the event because any column in the table potentially can be updated. All updates to the model should be done through this method so it should fire the event. You should not need to create a special method for each column. Also the TableModel can be changed directly without using a table editor. So the setValueAt(...) method can't assume it was invoked from a table editor. I'm not sure what you mean about "casting the model"?

Comment: My example would you require the OP to cast the model to his `user_AllBooks` implementation before been able to use the `setBorrowed` method.  Food for thought.  Thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ihave a question: Is this setValueAt(...) method for Jtable Of for abstractTableModel?

Comment: If it is for abstracttablemodel, Why it is not with other three methods when implemention methods?

Comment: @APoliteBoy Primarly about the table model, but the approach applies to both

Comment: @APoliteBoy the main reason, I would surmise, that setValue isn't an abstract method, is its not a requirement for table models to be editable

Comment: @MadProgrammer When i do this, it changed in jtable, but when run program again' it was not changed, because not changed in text file

Comment: How change from "no" to "yes" in text file too?

Comment: @Sajjad-HiFriend I would recommend that you raise another question. Let me know when you do so I can take a look

Comment: @MadProgrammer I ask this question in here:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837588/effect-jtable-cell-value-changing-on-text-file